# Docker Returned a non-zero code 100

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am trying to build a docker file and it keeps returning a non-zero code 100 for this part. Any ideas why?

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql zip
```

Comment: The simplest way to debug this is to run the base container `docker run -it php:7.1-fpm` and run the commands one by one until you hit the error

Comment: I was able to build it without any issue. Could you tell me the exact error message and also make sure proxy settings are correctly set.

Comment: I got the error: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y -f libmcrypt-dev     mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends     && pecl install imagick     && docker-php-ext-enable imagick     && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql zip' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: Do you confirm that proxy settings are correctly done? Try your example on play-with-docker `https://labs.play-with-docker.com`

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. It solved by adding

```
USER root
```

before running any Linux commands.

P.S: Seems to be an old question but I thought it may help somebody if put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on a slow internet connection. Eventually it worked after retrying a few times. When I moved to a faster download speed, it also solved it.